# Autocomplete and jeditable-datepicker not working together in Jeditable

Tags: jquery-ui, autocomplete, datepicker, conflict, jeditable

I am using  [jeditable](http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/jeditable) and i needed to integrate with [jeditable-datepicker](https://github.com/qertoip/jeditable-datepicker) and [Autocomplete](http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/jeditable/custom_autocomplete.html)

everything works fine apart from this incompatibility between them.

I have noticed that the problem is caused by the script

```
<script src="jquery-ui-1.8.24.custom.min.js"></script>
```

which makes working my jQuery datepicker, if i remove it the autocomplete starts working again but obviously my Jquery date picker stops working.

How can i figure it out my issue? there is a way to make them working together?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found the solution, i explain it here, it might be useful for someone in the future.

i have downloaded again the custom jQuery , i have deselected all the options just keeping the Datepicker Widget and then pasted the new script in my page and the incompatibility was gone!